# Apache Camel XSLT endpoint options with http resource

Tags: java, apache-camel

Camel's XSLT component has a number of configurable options. According to documentation, these options are added to the URI in the form of

```
?option=value&option=value&...
```

However, if the resource is coming over HTTP, all options are used as a query string for the HTTP request and then dropped. From XsltComponent.java:

```
// if its a http uri, then append additional parameters as they are part of the uri
if (ResourceHelper.isHttpUri(resourceUri)) {
    resourceUri = ResourceHelper.appendParameters(resourceUri, parameters);
}
```

and ResourceHelper.appendParameters():

```
if (!parameters.isEmpty()) {
    String query = URISupport.createQueryString(parameters);
    URI u = new URI(uri);
    u = URISupport.createURIWithQuery(u, query);
    parameters.clear();
    return u.toString();
}
```

The comment in XsltComponent makes me think this is functioning as designed, but it seems like it should be a pretty common scenario. Has anyone found a way around this? I don't want to copy the resources locally, as they are subject to change.

For reference, I'm using the Java DSL inside a Spring Boot application.

Answer (score 0):

No not all options, only any additional options that are not an option on the xslt component, for example if you have `....?foo=bar` then because `foo` is not an option on the xslt component it is used in the http url, as you may need to provide a few options there, to be able to access the resource.

Comment: Thanks for the response, Claus. However, I'm seeing something different.
The parameters list gets cleared in ResourceHelper.appendParameters() and is empty by the time XsltCopmonent.setProperties() gets called.

Comment: Okay then log a JIRA, however its not a good design either to load a xslt resource via http - it can be a bit flaky, imho its better to include it with your application. But stepping that aside those parameters should be configured on endpoint first before http uri